# 'elasticsearch' is not a registered wp command

Tags: wordpress, elasticsearch-plugin

Trying to install elasticpress plugin on wordpress multisite installation. This is a business directory which is setup on a multisite installation. Where each site on the multisite is a directory dedicated to a site.

It required "WP-CLI" and "ElasticSearch" server installed. Which has been installed and are running correctly. And post that when i am trying to index the posts using the command

> wp elasticpress index --setup --network-wide

which gives an error

> 'elasticsearch' is not a registered wp command

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

wp plugin install {plugin_name} {arguments}

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the plugin is network activated across all sites.